# WPF TreeView: bindings not updating when TreeView is virtualizing

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview

In my WPF app I have a TreeView with a lot of elements, so I turned on virtualization to speed up the rendering, like this:

```
<TreeView VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizing="True">
  ...
</TreeView>
```

However, if I do this it seems controls inside the tree items that are data-bound to properties in my Viewm Model stop reacting to the `OnPropertyChanged` event.

For example, let's assume I have the following template for my items:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModels:MyViewModel}">
  <TextBlock Text="{Binding ItemName}" />
</DataTemplate>
```

and the model is something like this:

```
public class MyViewModel: INotifyPropertyChanged {
  public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

  private string itemName;
  public string ItemName {
    get { return itemName; }
    set {
      if(value != itemName) {
        itemName = value;
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(ItemName)));
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The initial binding to the property works correctly and the item name is displayed in the TextBlock, but if the value of the `ItemName` property changes after the tree view item has already been rendered it will not update in the UI, as if the `PropertyChanged` event is being completely ignored.

How can I fix this? Note that if I set `VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizing="False"` the problem disappears, so it is definitely caused by the virtualization.

Comment: `new PropertyChangedEventArgs(ItemName)` is wrong. It must be `new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(ItemName))`.

Comment: @Clemens: yeah, that was a typo while copy-pasting the example for the question, thanks for pointing it out, I've edited the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the problem after further testing and debugging, it is not strictly related to the panel virtualization, I guess that was just a condition in which the bug manifests itself.

Basically, in my full code (that I omitted for brevity) the `ItemName` property is being set from inside an `Event Handler`. The problem was that my handler was triggered by events that were raised in a background thread somewhere else in the code and thus it did not run on the UI thread. I was under the impression that this wasn't a problem, since I was not manipulating any UI objects in the model (I was just touching my ViewModel object), however apparently if you're not in the UI thread raising the `PropertyChanged` becomes unreliable.

To solve the problem, I've wrapped the code in my handler in a dispatcher call, like this:

```
private void MyEvenHandler(object sender, MyEventArgs e)
{
    Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
    {
       var myViewModel = FindVm(e);
       myViewModel.ItemName = "updated";
    }
}
```

Now everything works as expected.

Comment: For me this is very strange.
In WPF, PropertyChanged can be raised on any thread, unlike UWP. In UWP, PropertyChanged needs to be raised on the UI thread.
Can you provide a separate Solution via GitHub with a minimal example that reproduces your problem.
I will be very curious to explore it deeper.

Comment: @EldHasp: unfortunately the full program is quite complex, and also uses the MaterialDesignXamlToolkit framework on top of standard WPF, so it's difficult for me to share a reduced sample. I don't know why it doesn't work from the background, but what I know is that invoking through the dispatcher solved the issue completely.